# Getting error message when trying to run macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have completed my VBA and I am attempting to run it.  When I go in and press F5 from the code window, it runs, but when I try and use the buttons in the actual workbook I am getting "Cannot run the macro.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

```
'Activating Sheet2 in EMM_Template
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

'Deleting Column E (Prod RICC)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete

'Deleting Row 3 (Title Row)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(3).EntireRow.Delete

'Selecting Range
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select

'Changing Font To Calibri 10
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Lrow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With .Cells(Lrow, "M")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "FUTURE" Then
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End With
    Next Lrow
End With

'Copying from Sheet2
'Activating/Pasting EMM_ETF
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Activate
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Range("A3").Select
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Rows("3:3").Insert shift:=xlDown

'Format Data
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select
            Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.RowHeight = 12.75
            Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Columns.ColumnWidth = 12

            Rows("1:1").EntireRow.AutoFit
            Rows("2:2").EntireRow.AutoFit

                With Sheets("EMM ETF").Rows("2:2").EntireRow
                    With .Font
                         .Size = 10
                    End With
                End With





'Deleting 0's from Col FGH
        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If Trim((Cells(i, 13).Value)) = "CURNCY" Then
                        Cells(i, 6).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                        Cells(i, 6).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                        Cells(i, 6).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                End If

        Next i

'Deleting 0's from Col IJK
        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If Trim((Cells(i, 13).Value)) = "STOCK" Then
                        Cells(i, 9).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                        Cells(i, 9).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                        Cells(i, 9).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                End If
        Next i

'Insert Column to for Action Autofill
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Range(Range("J3:L3"), Range("J3:L3").End(xlDown)).Select
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Range(Range("J3:L3"), Range("J3:L3").End(xlDown)).Cut
    Sheets("EMM ETF").Range("K3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


 'Match Action Rights to Last Comment
 Dim Rng As Range, x As Range

        With ActiveSheet

            Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                    For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "No Action", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No Action"

                    End If

                    Next x





            Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                    For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Rights", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Rights"

                    End If

                    Next




                Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Warrant", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Warrant"

                    End If



                     Next x



                Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Pinksheet", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Pinksheet"

                    End If



                    Next x



                Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Desk", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Desk to adjust"

                    End If



                    Next x



                Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Asset", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Asset Servicing"

                End If

                Next x



                Set Rng = .Range("I3:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                For Each x In Rng

                    If InStr(1, x.Text, "Journal", 1) > 0 Then
                    x.Offset(0, 1).Value = "MO Journal"

                End If

                Next x

        End With


'Detect/Cut/Insert/CCY
        Dim CorrectPosition As Integer

        CorrectPosition = getCorrectPosition("Ccy")
        Call MoveRows("K", "CURNCY", CorrectPosition)

        'Detect/Cut/Insert/Foreign
        CorrectPosition = getCorrectPosition("Foreign")
        Call MoveRows("A", "FRGN3", CorrectPosition)

'Changing Font To Calibri 10
    With Sheets("EMM ETF").Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With

'Final Sort


End Sub

Function getCorrectPosition(StringToLookFor As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If (Cells(i, 1) = StringToLookFor) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

getCorrectPosition = i + 2
End Function

Sub MoveRows(columnName As String, LookupValue As String, positionToPaste As Integer)
        With Sheets("EMM ETF")
            For Lrow = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                    With .Cells(Lrow, columnName)
                        If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                            If .Value = LookupValue Then
                                .EntireRow.Cut
                                Cells(positionToPaste, 1).Select
                                Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
                                Lrow = 1
                            ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                                Exit For

                            End If

                        End If
                    End With
            Next Lrow
        End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to know what might be happening without knowing your code.  Can you post your code?  Also, what do you mean by "buttons"? Did you add buttons to your sheet, or do you mean View->Macros, then running from there?  Also, where *is* the macro? Is it in a module for that workbook, your personal workbook, etc?

Comment: I agree with @BruceWayne! Further to his questions, are the controls ActiveX or Form controls?

Comment: Hey @BruceWayne and MiguelH -- So I have 3 actual buttons that I added to the sheet to run 3 different Subs I guess.  These buttons are on a sheet in the workbook that also contains the 3 sheets where the macro does its work.  I will post some code below here for reference.  Thanks guys!

Comment: 'Changing Font To Calibri 10
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 10
        End With
    End With
    
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Lrow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With .Cells(Lrow, "M")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "FUTURE" Then
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            End With
    Next Lrow
End With

Comment: Add the code to your original post (click "edit") and then highlight, and click the `{}` to format as code.

Comment: Thanks!  Is that the whole macro (I don't see the `Sub subName()` at the start)? Also, where is that macro? It should, I believe, be in a module in that workbook (as opposed to being in a sheet).

Comment: Ah apologies I missed the Subname at the beginning when copying but it is there.  This is a large chunk of the macro but not all.  So it is actually on a different sheet.  IE- the first 3 sheets are the data sheets, and the 4th sheet is named MACRO and holds the 3 buttons that I want to use to run it.  I am unfamiliar with the idea of a module, this is all a new learning experience to me if you could explain a little further.  Thanks!

Comment: **How** did you assign the macros to the buttons?

Comment: Do you have any other workbooks open when trying to run the Macro?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to save the workbook as a macro enabled workbook and reopen it again. If prompted to enable macro click ok.